# No module requests found - Visual Studio code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, module, pip

I cannot run a code in Visual Studio Code with import requests. I installed requests with `pip install requests` and it still doesn't work. I tried uninstalling it and installing it again but this didn't work either.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\code\Projects\Project\project.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

Tried doing it via the terminal which didn't work either.

Comment: Restart VS code. Have you tried doing it via the terminal?

Comment: paste the traceback

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

After selecting python interpreter, open a **new integrated** terminal then run

```
pip show requests
```

If you can get detailed information, reload window should solve `no module found` error;

If it shows `WARNING: Package(s) not found: requests`, please reinstall it.